I have some problems with non blocking pipes in my c program
I an trying to create a program in c that has one parent process and three child ones. The aim is that the parent will be connected with each child with two pipes so when the children choose to send a message to one  of their siblings they will send it first to the parent and then it will send it to the appropriate child. The read ends of the parent have to be non-blocking .
I have tried to follow the example that is in the https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/non-blocking-io-with-pipes-in-c/ site . The two errors that I have are the following:
array type has incomplete element type 'int[]'  void parent_read(int pipes[][]) (line 11)
type of formal parameter is incomplete parent_read(pipes); (line140)

What can I do to fix it? And is what I have done till now in regards to non-blocking correct?
Thanks
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MSGSIZE 5

void parent_read(int pipes[][])
{
    int nread;
    char buf[MSGSIZE];

    // write link
    close(pipes[1]);

    while (1) {

        // read call if return -1 then pipe is
        // empty because of fcntl
        nread = read(pipes[0], buf, MSGSIZE);
        switch (nread) {
        case -1:

            // case -1 means pipe is empty and errono
            // set EAGAIN
            if (errno == EAGAIN) {
                printf("(pipe empty)\n");
                sleep(1);
                break;
            }

            else {
                perror("read");
                exit(4);
            }

        // case 0 means all bytes are read and EOF(end of conv.)
        case 0:
            printf("End of conversation\n");

            // read link
            close(pipes[0]);

            exit(0);
        default:

            // text read
            // by default return no. of bytes
            // which read call read at that time
            printf("MSG = %s\n", buf);
        }
    }
}



int main()
{
    int pids[3],id[3];
    int pipes[6][2];
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<6;i++)
    {
        if (pipe(pipes[i])==-1)
        {
            printf("Error in pipe: %d\n",i);
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Error in pipe:!\n");
        }
    }

     if (fcntl(pipes[0][0], F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK) < 0)
     {
         exit(2);
     }
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        pids[i]=fork();

        if(pids[i]==0)
        {
            id[i]=getpid();
            //printf("ID:%d\n",id[i]);
             break;
        }
    }
    if (getpid()==id[0])
        {
            for (i=0;i<6;i++)
            {
                if (i>0 && i>1)
                {
                    close(pipes[i][0]);
                    close(pipes[i][1]);
                    printf("Pipes of A have closed:%d\n",i);
                }
            }
           /* char* x="hello";
          if (write(pipes[1][1],&x,sizeof(int)) == -1)
            {
               printf("error in  write");
            }*/
            return 0;
        }
    if (getpid()==id[1])
        {
            for (i=0;i<6;i++)
            {
                if ((i>2 && i>3) || (i<2 && i<3))
                {
                    close(pipes[i][0]);
                    close(pipes[i][1]);
                    printf("Pipes of B have closed:%d\n",i);
                }
            }
            return 0;
        }
    if (getpid()==id[2])
        {
             for (i=0;i<6;i++)
            {
                if (i<4 && i<5)
                {
                    close(pipes[i][0]);
                    close(pipes[i][1]);
                    printf("Pipes of C have closed:%d\n",i);
                }
            }
            return 0;
        }
    if(getpid()!=0)
    {
       // char y;
        parent_read(pipes); //Here i try to call parent read
        //read(pipes[1][0],&y,sizeof(int));
        //printf("The child processe has given:%y",y);
        for(i=0;i<=3;i++)
        {
            wait(NULL);

        }
        printf("PARENT:%d\n",getpid());
    }
}


The code is not finish for the purpose i want it to do. So i am just asking about the non blocking part . If someone has any examples or something for me to read it will be appreciated

The problem you are having is not with pipes but with basic C. When you define a function with two dimensional array as a parameter, you need to specify the second dimension. Regarding the rest - you should ask specific questions, there is relatively a lot of code.

int x[][] is invalid C.
C17 6.7.6.2 Array declarators:

Constraints
/--/
The element type shall not be an incomplete or function
type

An array which does not have the size specified is an incomplete type. So in case of int x[][], it is an array of incomplete type which in turn has an element type int [] which is also incomplete. So that violates the above language constraint.

So why can we declare a function parameter int x[] with a single dimension? First of all, the element type here is int so it is fine as per the above rule.
Next we need to know that a function's array parameters are implicitly "adjusted" by the compiler into a pointer to the first element (see C17 6.7.6.3). This works just like when an array is used in an expression - it "decays" into a pointer to the first element.
So if we declare void func (int x[]), that's fine even though we didn't specify the array size. Because it will get adjusted into int* x anyway and therefore the specified array size doesn't matter.
There's another requirement that once the adjustment is done, then we must have a parameter which is a "complete object type":
C17 6.7.6.3

After adjustment, the parameters in a parameter type list in a function declarator that is part of a definition of that function shall not have incomplete type.

And that's fine too since we have an int* - a pointer is a complete object type.
